# MySql foreign key, how it actually works

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

Maybe a newbie question about foreign keys, but I want to know the answer.

Let's say I have 2 tables:

```
products
--------
product_id (int)
name (unique) (varchar)
description (text)
vendor (varchar) (foreign key: vendors.name)
```

AND

```
vendors
--------
name (varchar)
```

I know that I should use a `vendor_id (int)`, but this is just an example to help me ask my question.

So: if I create vendor: Apple, and product: 1, iPhone 4, Description.., Apple then the varchar "Apple" will be stored both in products and vendors, or just in vendors (because of the foreign key)?
Is this a wrong db design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called "normalization" in the database.  In your example, there are a couple things to consider:

1. In order for `products` to have a foreign key to `vendors`, `vendors` needs a key.  Is `name` the primary key for `vendors`?  If so, then the foreign key would also be a `varchar`.  In that case, yes, the value "Apple" would be stored in both.  (Note that this isn't a very good idea.)
2. If you add a `vendor_id` integer column to the `vendors` table, and it is the primary key for that table, then you can add a `vendor_id` (or any other name) column to the `products` table and make it a foreign key to the `vendors` table.  In this case, only that integer would be stored in both tables.  This is where the data becomes normalized.  A small, simpler data type (integer) links the tables, which contain the actual data which describes the records.

Only that key value is stored in both tables.  It's used as a reference to join the tables when selecting data.  For example, in order to select a given product and its vendor, you'd do something like this:

```
SELECT products.name, products.description, vendors.name AS vendor
FROM products INNER JOIN vendors ON products.vendor_id = vendors.vendor_id
WHERE products.product_id = ?id
```

This would "join" the two tables into a single table (not really, just for the query) and select the record from it.

Answer (score 1):

It will be stored in both. The foreign-key constraint requires that every value in `products.vendor` appear somewhere in `vendor.name`.

(By the way, note that MySQL only enforces foreign-key constraints if the storage engine is InnoDB.)